Synchronous reads are not supported - for Blazor Server InputStream Read (Blazorise)
Seeing a "Synchronous reads are not supported" error in the inputStream.Read(buffer) for the following code:
public static void FileDecrypt(IFileEntry file, string newFileName, string key)
{
    FileStream fsCrypt = new(fileName, FileMode.Create);
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        aes.IV = iv;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BYTES];
        int read;

        using Stream inputStream = file.OpenReadStream();
        try
        {
            // ********* Fails on this READ with Unsupported ******
            while ((read = inputStream.Read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                byte[] result = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, read);
                fsCrypt.Write(result, 0, read);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

What is puzzling, is the inputStream.Read(buffer) WORKS for the following code:
public static void FileEncrypt(IFileEntry file, string newFileName, string key)
{
    FileStream fsCrypt = new(fileName, FileMode.Create);
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        aes.IV = iv;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        // Write the results in 1 megabyte chunks
        byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BYTES];
        int read;

        using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)fsCrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        using Stream inputStream = file.OpenReadStream();
        try
        {
            // WORKS here!
            while ((read = inputStream.Read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

I am sure it is probably something simple, but I can't see it. I am using the Blazorise IFileEntry file, but I also tried the IBrowserFile construct from standard file upload with the same result. Trying to buffer the input into the decryption because I think the file sizes could get large.
I also tried the ReadAsync() method but it simply hits that line and then never returns.

Are both pieces (esp the first one) executed on Blazor server?  The error only makes sense for Blazor Wasm.

@HenkHolterman It is Blazor Wasm, which I thought was server side rendered. New to Blazor

The "Synchronous reads are not supported" error is correct when running on WebAssembly. All I/O has to go through JS Interop and that is asynchronous all the way.  Every synchronous operation will throw.
The fix is to make your methods async:
//static void FileDecrypt(IFileEntry file, string newFileName, string key)
  static async Task FileDecrypt(IFileEntry file, string newFileName, string key)

and perform all I/O async:
   // while ((read = inputStream.Read(buffer)) > 0)
      while ((read = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer)) > 0)


Thank will give it a try.
